# plot.ts with years at x-axis

Tags: r, plot, time-series, axis

I looked everywhere but still could not figure out my little problem.
I have a data frame like this:

```
     GerProd_sum_PerYear
1997           369332000
1998           399127000
1999           396103500
2000           506698500
2001           417757000
2002           440025882
2003           499654816
2004           533781000
2005           565508000
2006           600001000
2007           695574663
2008           543780271
2009           496257990
2010           547352965
2011           554533553
2012           532066522
2013           535117263
```

I would like to plot.ts (or just plot), so that the years (1997 to 2013) are at the x-axis.

So far I have done this:

```
test<-plot.ts(df, type= "b", main = "Amounts over time", xlab = "Years", las=3, ylab = "Amounts per year")
```

It looks fine BUT the x achsis is 1 to 17, as there is 17 values.... I would like the 1 to 17 replaced by 1997 to 2013.

Help :)

Comment: Have you formatted your data as time series data? Have a look at `help(ts)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `ts`:

```
data <- "Date GerProd_sum_PerYear
1997 369332000
1998 399127000
1999 396103500
2000 506698500
2001 417757000
2002 440025882
2003 499654816
2004 533781000
2005 565508000
2006 600001000
2007 695574663
2008 543780271
2009 496257990
2010 547352965
2011 554533553
2012 532066522
2013 535117263"

df <- read.table(text=data, header=T, sep=" ",as.is=T)
timeseries <- ts(df$GerProd_sum_PerYear, start = 1997)
plot.ts(timeseries, type= "b", main = "Amounts over time", xlab = "Years", las=3, ylab = "Amounts per year")
```

[image]

(but consider using `xts` or `zoo`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the years are defined as row.names, and so not considered in the `plot.ts`. I would go for the base plot in this way :

```
df <- 
read.csv(text=
"GerProd_sum_PerYear
1997,369332000
1998,399127000
1999,396103500
2000,506698500
2001,417757000
2002,440025882
2003,499654816
2004,533781000
2005,565508000
2006,600001000
2007,695574663
2008,543780271
2009,496257990
2010,547352965
2011,554533553
2012,532066522
2013,53511726",row.names=1)

years <- as.numeric(row.names(df))

test<-plot(x=years,y=df$GerProd_sum_PerYear, type= "b", 
           main = "Amounts over time", xlab = "Years", las=3, 
           ylab = "Amounts per year",xaxt='n') 
#xaxt='n' means do not draw the ticks, we will do it manually in the next line
axis(side=1,at=years,las=2) #las=2 means perpendicular labels
```

[image]

Comment: And then how do I manage to have all the years shown, as in steps of 1 year as opposed to 5 years....

Comment: Wow, it looks perfect now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. You should consider upvoting and accepting answers if you think they're useful